# How to mock Axios inside a custom function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, axios, jestjs

## Question

How can I mock `axios.get()` when it is inside my own custom function?

I am completely lost at this point. Hope someone can see what I am doing wrong.

## Details

I have the below `getString()` function which downloads the html from a website and returns a value `> 0` if the string was found and `-1` if string not found.

Since `getString()` uses `axios.get()` to download the html, I would like to Jest mock this call.

[This article](https://stackabuse.com/using-mocks-for-testing-in-javascript-with-jes/) is the closest I can find to my situation, but in his case, he mocks a standalone `axios.request()`, where mine `axios.get()` is inside my custom `getString()`.

My attempt is this:

**getString.test.js**

```
const axios = require('axios');
const getString = require('./getString');

jest.mock('./getString', () => {
  return {
    baseURL: 'localhost',
    get: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({
      data: 'xxx If you are the website administrator xxx'
    }),
  }
});
```

**packages.json**

```
{
  "name": "jest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "getString.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

I have done `npm init -y && npm install --save-dev jest`, but `npm run test` gives me

```
$ npm run test

> jest@1.0.0 test /home/mje/projects/jest
> jest

sh: jest: command not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! jest@1.0.0 test: `jest`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the jest@1.0.0 test script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?
```

The simple PoC works from [the docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/getting-started).

**index.js**

```
const getString = require('./getString');

(async function(){
  'use strict'

  const isOk = await getString({
    url:          'http://localhost',
    string:       'If you are the website administrator',
    timeout:      1000,
    maxRedirects: 0
  });

  console.log(isOk);
})();
```

**getString.js**

```
const axios = require('axios');
const qs = require('qs');

module.exports = async (options) => {
  options              = options || {};
  options.url          = options.url || {};
  options.string       = options.string || null;
  options.timeout      = options.timeout || 1000;
  options.maxRedirects = options.maxRedirects || 0;

  try {
    const response = await axios.get(options.url, {
      timeout: options.timeout,
      maxRedirects: options.maxRedirects,
      validateStatus: null,
      transformResponse: [function (data) {
        return data.search(options.string);
  }]
    });
    return await response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    return -1;
  }
};
```

Comment: do you have `jest` installed as dependency ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First verify if `jest` is within your dependencies, and if it's not - install it

```sh
yarn add --dev jest || npm i -D jest
```

and then test your implementation by mocking `axios` rather than the implementation that you want to test.

And the rest of the `getString` could look something like this

```js
const axios = require('axios');
const getString = require('./getString');

jest.mock('axios')

const mockResponseData = {
  hello: "world"
}

describe('getString', () => {
  describe('axios returning resolved promise', () => {
    beforeAll(() => {
      // returning transformed mock
      axios.get.mockResolvedValue({
        data: mockResponseData
      })
    })

    describe('called with arguments', () => {
      let result
      beforeAll(() => {
        result = getString({
          url: 'http://localhost',
          string: 'If you are the website administrator',
          timeout: 1000,
          maxRedirects: 0
        })
      })

      it('should call axios.get', async () => {
        await result
        expect(axios.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
          "http://localhost",
          {
            "maxRedirects": 0,
            "timeout": 1000,
            "transformResponse": [
              expect.any(Function)
            ],
            "validateStatus": null
          }
        )
      })

      it('should return the response.data', async () => {
        expect(await result).toEqual(mockResponseData)
      })
    })
  })

  describe('axios returning rejected promise', () => {
    beforeAll(() => {
      // returning transformed mock
      axios.get.mockRejectedValue({
        data: mockResponseData
      })
    })

    describe('called with arguments', () => {
      let result
      beforeAll(() => {
        result = getString({
          url: 'http://localhost',
          string: 'If you are the website administrator',
          timeout: 1000,
          maxRedirects: 0
        })
      })

      it('should return -1', async () => {
        expect(await result).toEqual(-1)
      })
    })
  })
})
```

**Edit:** in order to achieve 100% coverage you'll also have to test your implementation's `transformResponse` and in order to do that you can mock the implementation like this

```js
// this is not tested
import mockResponseBody from './localMock.json';

axios.get.mockImplementation((url, { transformResponse }) =>
    Promise.resolve({
        data: transformResponse.reduce((acc, fn) => fn(acc), mockResponseData)
    })
)
```

[working example](https://repl.it/@StefanTenev/jest-playground#getString.test.js)

Comment: How do you run the test? `npm run test`? When I do that on your repl.it, then it says `Error: no test specified`, so I imagine you run it in a different way?

Comment: @SandraSchlichting on repl.it just press the `Run` button above. In the command line using `npm run test` should be working with the default configuration

Comment: Thank you so much for the working test! I will look into it now in more detail. The command not found issue did I just figure out. I had my files in `~/projects/jest/` and when doing `npm init -y` it takes the directory name `jest` and inserts that in `package.json` and `npm i -D jest` won't accept that... Now `npm run test` works locally =)

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: Why doesn't all the tests fail given `mockResponseData` doesn't contain the string `If you are the website administrator`? I would have expected that `mockResponseData` contained `If you are the website administrator`, and tests would only succeed, if that string is found?

Comment: @SandraSchlichting because in my repl.it example the `transformResponse` is not taken into account

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224367/discussion-between-sandra-schlichting-and-teneff).

Comment: hi @Teneff I see u have a good experience with jest can you please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64770117/testing-react-app-with-jest-and-enzyme-token-problem