# Testing react app with jest and enzyme token problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, jestjs, enzyme

I have a react app in which I have added unit testing, but one of my tests fails,

Here is my test file, I want to test action creators `getUser`.

[image]

When I run `npm test` I get the following error,

```
FAIL   UnitTests  resources/js/tests/actions/index.test.js

  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null

       8 |              'Accept': 'application/json',
       9 |              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    > 10 |              'X-CSRF-TOKEN': document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content')
         |                              ^
      11 |      },
      12 | });
      13 | 

      at Object.<anonymous> (utils/api.js:10:19)
      at Object.<anonymous> (store/actions/userActions.js:2:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (store/actions/index.js:2:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (tests/actions/index.test.js:3:1)
```

What do I need to do to solve this problem? any idea or solution will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Well, short version is - you don't have a DOM element which you use in your file - you have two options - mocking `document.querySelector` method, so that it return object with `getAttribute` method, or creating element manually in jest-dom, like:

```
  let metaElement;
  beforeAll(() => {
    metaElement = document.createElement("meta");
    metaElement.name = "csrf-token";
    metaElement.content = "test-token";
    document.head.append(metaElement);
  })
  afterAll(() => {
    metaElement.remove();
  });
```

I don't know however both code of file you're testing, and mocking library you use (`moxios`) :)

Comment: Hej that does not solve the problem :(  unfortunatelly

Answer (score 3):

You get the error `Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null`, which means that `document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]')` have returned `null`.

In order to change that you have two **options**:

1. Modify the document as per [Emazaw's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64770265/637367)

### OR

2. Use `jest.spyOn` to spy on `document.querySelector` to modify it's behaviour

```js
// this should be called before attempting to read the meta's attribute
jest.spyOn(document, 'querySelector').mockReturnValue({
  getAttribute: jest.fn().mockReturnValue('MOCK-CSRF-TOKEN-VALUE')
})
```

Comment: do you mean something like this? https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-breeze-b8v83?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Yes, but I've said you've got two options, so you pick the one or the other, not both :D

Comment: Yep, unfortunatelly still getting the same error that is weird :( https://ibb.co/9s0gbjL

Comment: @TheDeadMan probably you'll have to share the contents of `api.js`. My guess is that probably `getAttrbute` is executed immediately after it's imported

Comment: Indeed it is immediately invoked once `api.js` is required, so you can try adding removing the `import actions ....` and adding it as `const actions = require('store/actions')` after the `jest.spyOn`

Comment: unfortunatelly I get the same error here is how I changed https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-breeze-b8v83?file=/src/App.js